# set Webview to render content with a specific amount of space at top of content

Tags: android, android-webview

**Goal:**
I need some space at the top of the content as if the HTML starts off with `<BR><BR><BR>`
However, I don't want to inject a bunch of those manually because I need to control the amount of space in terms of DP's

How can it be done ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't just set a top margin on the webview?

Comment: if I use a layout margin for the webview, wouldn't the margin always show even when the user has scrolled down ? I just want there to be blank space at the beginning of the content (maybe like a listview header?) but after the user has begun scrolling the content, the content should be flush against the top of the webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `android:layout_marginTop="xxdp"` in your webview attributes.

You can set the background of the activity to a specific color like white so it doesn't seem odd to the user, if you want to.

Comment: no that's not it because the margin is there for ever above the webview. What I need is: within the webview, have a certain amount of empty space before the top of the HTML content. Once the user has scrolled down, the HTML content should be flush against the top of the webview.

Comment: then change the layout_marginTop dynamically. Get the view and change its parameters when the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

How I did it in my app was make a second **empty** `LinearLayout` and place it above the  layout that includes the webview.  For example:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    //webview
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then I resized the first LinearLayout to a percentage in the GUI.

That's probably the absolute worst way to achieve your goal, but it worked for me.